# Cannot find executable for CFBundle CertUIFramework.axbundle

Tags: xcode, xcode5, xcode6

Just updated to Xcode 5 and this is the first error its throwing on the logger for all my apps. Can't seem to understand why this is happening.

```
    2013-09-19 10:46:54.341 MyApp[1156:a0b] Cannot find executable 
for CFBundle 0x8a7c7a0 </Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/
iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk/
System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/CertUIFramework.axbundle> (not loaded)
```

**Edit (11-11-2013):** *To everyone reading, once I waiting for a solid working solution to accept and close. The highest voted answer works until you re-open the project only.*

**Edit (30-09-2014):** *I can see this has been sorted since XCode 6 has been released! Finally*

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xcode 5 Error CertUIFramework.axbundle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18036381/xcode-5-error-certuiframework-axbundle)

Comment: Oops.  Actually this post is better anyway and looks to contain the answer: https://devforums.apple.com/message/863467#863467

Answer (score 154, accepted):

Final Edit-

> Temporary workaround: click iOS Simulator > Reset Content and
> Settings... and run again.
>
> This error message may reappear at random. For me, it happens when I
> launch a different application. There are several threads in [Apple dev
> forums](https://devforums.apple.com/search.jspa?resultTypes=MESSAGE&peopleEnabled=true&q=CertUIFramework.axbundle) and in StackOverflow about this problem, but none have a
> definitive answer. This seems to be a SDK error to be fixed in the
> next Xcode version.
>
> Updated: October 3.

CREDIT - Please check this answer - [Xcode 5 Error CertUIFramework.axbundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18036381/xcode-5-error-certuiframework-axbundle?rq=1)

**Further Edit**
Although this was potentially the issue resolution at the time. I believe some of the newer answers below relating to the better touch tool are in fact the correct resolutions.

Comment: Did you copy that answer from the following question?  If so mark this question as a dupe. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345263/cannot-find-executable-for-cfbundle-cfplugin-error

Comment: No, it is not exactly the same issue here, but the answer could well be the same.

Comment: I had to remove the accept answer because the problem return on second build. Every time its not feasible to reset the simulator.

Comment: Yes - I have had similar issues with this too... I have reset the simulator a few times. I presume this is a bit of an Xcode5 bug... we will see, but it does resolve the issue

Comment: please add a summary of the answer. Just linking is not good style

Comment: Yes, it's only on simulator! Try with a real device.

Answer (score 28):

After reading Kirill's answer I did some digging as I didn't want to disable BetterTouchTool for everything just the "iOS Simulator" and you can.
Open the "iOS Simulator" and will it as the active app go to the BTT drop-down menu from the top bar (of that screen if you have more than one) and select "Disable BTT for Current App". It will turn to a play icon when it's disabled.
Make sure the app name on the bar is still "iOS Simulator" as mine jumped to "Finder" a few times when I clicked the top bar!

[image: BTT disabled for current app]

Now re-set the simulator (if it doesn't work) and rebuild. You shouldn't get the error! :)
Don't forget to clear the error if it's still there. ;)

BTT seems to remember what apps it's disabled for (or at least it does when you close and re-open the app that's disabled I haven't tried a system re-boot yet).

Answer (score 16):

Its easy. Go iOS simulator and reset content and setting.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

If you are using XCode-5 then just reset the simulator "Reset Content and Settings" and run once again

Comment: which is the previous answer but it keeps coming back everytime.

Comment: I think even after that error statement application works fine, Do not worry much about it and still XCode-5 have many bugs, Apple might fix the problem in next version of Xcode

Answer (score 7):

So I was having this error too in Xcode 5 and 5.1. I wanted to figure out if it's Xcode bug or something else, so I did a fresh install of Mavericks 10.9.2 and Xcode 5.1. Everything seemed fine after multiple tests.

Here is where the problem began. I put the apps and settings that I mostly use and the error came back. So I deleted everything and started adding everything one by one. After couple days I had bingo! The problem is with BetterSnapTool and BetterTouchTool

**Update 12.12.2014**

Just started using Xcode 6.1 and noticed that this bug seems to be gone at least with Xcode 6.1 simulators and BTT 0.9985 versions.

**Update:** 
As GasB pointed out, it is possible to disable BTT for certain apps. So just disable it for iOS Simulator. You just have to remember not to use gestures while using the simulator as that triggers the error message.

**Simple solution:**

Remove the ticks in preference pane, reset simulator and do clean build. The error message will disappear.
[image: No control for the apps].

Comment: I'll be the first to say: Good find :)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and solved it setting the '**Localization native development region**' to match my systems region. In my case from 'en' to 'de'. The referenced files are stored in localized versions in your filesystem. So this setting is used to identify the needed version.

You can find that setting in your project settings at 'Info' -> 'Custom iOS Target Properties'.

Answer (score 3):

Resetting the simulator ‘fixes’ it because it turns the accessibility support off. You can normally achieve the same by simply disabling the ‘Accessibility Inspector’ in the ‘Settings’ app.

If, however, you need it enabled, particularly hate this error message, and are feeling adventurous then you can use the following monkey patches to silence the error: https://gist.github.com/alloy/9277316. (Be sure to NOT include this in your release builds.)

Answer (score 2):

Resetting the simulator is a PITA, I found a way to get rid of these messages without having to to this:

- go to Settings > Accessibility
- turn on Accessibility Inspector
- turn off Accessibility Inspector
- quit Simulator

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with Xcode 5 in ML 10.8.5

I re-installed Mountain Lion (in a Parallels' VM), then update ML to 10.8.5.

Then installrd Xcode 5, and it's worked fine.

I think that the error is caused by a third SW installed in ML.

Comment: I think the solution works, but reinstalling my development machine OS is super tedious task, and I'm sure time is our enemy in finding the true culprit of this warning.

Answer (score 1):

The application Moom is also causing this issue, and I couldn't find a way to disable it for just the iOS Simulator. So for now I disabled it's accessibility features.

Comment: can you share some instructions to disable Moom

Comment: Go to System Preserences / Security / Privacy (tab) / Accessibility (list item) then find Moom in the list to the right and uncheck it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm on Mavericks (10.9.3) and encountered the same error in xCode(5.1.1).

I tried anything - reinstalling xCode from both AppStore and dmg. Resetting the emulator resulted in the same error and deleting the Simulator SDK folder gave no results too.

The issue on my end was indeed Moom as mentioned by @aorcsik! Disabling it's accessibility, followed by clean (cmd+shift+k) in xCode cleared the error.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open `Disk Utility` and apply `Repair Disk Permissions` in Macintosh HD.
2. After doing above step, apply `Reset Contents and Settings` in iOS Simulator.

This above solution can definitely fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, and none of the answers in this thread could fix it. Mine was simple UI with a UIDatePicker. I resolved it by removing the UIDatePicker and the associated code, then added them in again. Problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

For me it was Keyboard Maestro, adding the simulator to Maestro's exclude list silenced the warnings