# XCode not loading libraries properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

The solution I have seen is to reset the simulator. but doesn't help.

Getting these errors.

```
2013-10-20 13:27:11.097 a[2204:a0b] Cannot find executable for CFBundle 0xddc93b0 </Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/GeoServices.axbundle> (not loaded)
2013-10-20 13:27:11.143 a[2204:a0b] Cannot find executable for CFBundle 0xddf2b60 </Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/CertUIFramework.axbundle> (not loaded)
2013-10-20 13:27:11.148 a[2204:a0b] Cannot find executable for CFBundle 0xdd6a2e0 </Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/MusicLibrary.axbundle> (not loaded)
2013-10-20 13:27:11.151 a[2204:a0b] Cannot find executable for CFBundle 0xdd67b20 </Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/StoreKitFramework.axbundle> (not loaded)
2013-10-20 13:27:11.166 a[2204:a0b] Cannot find executable for CFBundle 0xd9cf6e0 </Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/SocialFramework.axbundle> (not loaded)
2013-10-20 13:27:11.170 a[2204:a0b] Cannot find executable for CFBundle 0xd9d5f20 </Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/TwitterFramework.axbundle> (not loaded)
```

Comment: Have you tried repairing disk permissions using Disk Utility?

Comment: Repost on internal apple Xcode forum

Comment: @neilco reparied disk permissions using disk utility. Still getting those messages.

Comment: Im having the same problem with different Frameworks.

Comment: I have the same problem with the first three of your Frameworks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18888059/cannot-find-executable-for-cfbundle-certuiframework-axbundle/21952086#21952086 try this link.Thanks

Answer (score 55, accepted):

**iOS Simulator > Reset content and settings...**

helped me to solve the same problem.