# Populating table view with Blog JSON Data

Tags: ios, json, uitableview

So this is my Code:

**TableViewController.h**

```
@interface TableViewController : UITableViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *blogPosts;

@end
```

**TableViewController.m**

```
   - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        NSURL *blogURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/api/get_recent_summary/"];

        NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:blogURL];

        NSError *error = nil;

        NSDictionary *dataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData
                                                                       options:0 error:&error];



        self.blogPosts  = [dataDictionary objectForKey:@"posts"];
}
```

**With this being displayed on the log**

2014-04-15 20:21:48.884 BlogReader[772:60b] Cannot find executable for CFBundle 0xa181ef0  (not loaded)

Comment: are you sure that this happened in this code? can you debug step by step and send the line of code that caused error?

Comment: Check this I suppose that is your issue: [answer link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18888059/cannot-find-executable-for-cfbundle-certuiframework-axbundle

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to make sure that the Author and Title strings matched the same ones as the ones in the JSON

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSDictionary *blogPost = [self.blogPosts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    // Extracting 'Title' and 'Author' from dictionary to display in cell
    cell.textLabel.text = [blogPost valueForKey:@"title"];

    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [blogPost valueForKey:@"author"];

    return cell;
}
```