# XCode Tests keep failing

Tags: xcode, unit-testing, xctest

I'm trying to run tests for my app, i'm able to get to a point where it launches the app in the simulator, but then gives this error and all tests fail:

```
2014-05-23 12:49:30.276 App[20472:60b] Cannot find executable for CFBundle 0xd04e190 </Users/Kalyan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-gkggxfqpxbiszkbmoqpwtzlklpem/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AppTests.octest> (not loaded)
IDEBundleInjection.c: Error loading bundle '/Users/Kalyan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-gkggxfqpxbiszkbmoqpwtzlklpem/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AppTests.octest'
```

I'm not sure what the issue is, but I have read many forums on this. Seems like its some sort of configuration issue but i'm not able to put a finger on it.

Some people mentioned in the simulator going to `Simulator > Reset Content & Settings`, but that didn't help.

I have tried reading the below to no avail:

[Cannot find executable for CFBundle CertUIFramework.axbundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18888059/cannot-find-executable-for-cfbundle-certuiframework-axbundle)

https://github.com/kif-framework/KIF/issues/310

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/rubymotion/_tcikfIkPNo/oIp9oCrZzcwJ

Is there anything else I haven't tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This took me forever to figure out, but just in case somebody else is having this issue, goto the project settings, and then click on the `Tests` project.

Goto Build Settings. Search for **Wrapper Extensions** under **Packaging**. Make sure it's the appropriate one. Currently it should be `xctest`.