# How to store JSON data in a file?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I am building an article reading iOS app.

I have a `.json` file in match folder named as `Data.json`
I am not able to write data into it.

Here is my code:

```
- (void)writeJsonToFile {
    //applications Documents dirctory path
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    //live json data url
    NSString *stringURL = ysURL;
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
    NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    //file to write to

    NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory, @"Data.json"];
    //attempt to download live data
    if (urlData) {

        [urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
    }
    //copy data from initial package into the applications Documents folder
    else {
        //file to write to

        NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",  documentsDirectory, @"Data.json"];
        //file to copy from
        NSString *json = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Data" ofType:@"json" inDirectory:@"/match/Data.json"];
        NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:json options:kNilOptions error:nil];

        //write file to device
        [jsonData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: No offense, but those weird log messages only make your code harder to read.

Comment: @Jenox,I have deleted the log messages,now you can read easily.

Comment: How do you know you're not able to write data into the file?  Error messages?  Do you try and re-read the data?  If you run it on the simulator, you can find the simulator's files in: ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator.

Comment: @Owen Hartnett In console i'm getting this message:</Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/CertUIFramework.axbundle> (not loaded)

Comment: Did you have a question??

Comment: @Hot Licks,Yes i'm unable to solve this problem.

Comment: What problem?  You're not checking for errors anywhere so you apparently don't think you have any possible problems.  You;re not logging the file path you're using to see if it's really what you think it is.  Not doing a lot of stuff one would do if they thought they might have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

can you tell us more about the problem you have ?

1) You don't have to redefine the `filePath` in the else because you already did before.

```
NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory, @"Data.json"];
```

And you should use `stringByAppendingPathComponent` which automaticaly add the `/` you will need or not :

```
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Data.json]
```

2) Are you sure your Data.json is include in your project ? do you get a nil ?

```
    NSString *json = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Data" ofType:@"json" inDirectory:@"/match/Data.json"];
```

3)  For the problem of not load : `</Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.pl​atform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/CertUIFramework.axbundle> (not loaded)`

[Cannot find executable for CFBundle CertUIFramework.axbundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18888059/cannot-find-executable-for-cfbundle-certuiframework-axbundle)

Answer (score 0):

Try using NSStrings method to write the file, and check your error code:

```
NSURL *fileUrl = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource: @"Data" withExtension:@"json"];
NSError * error;
[json writeToURL:fileUrl atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
NSLog(@"%@",error.localizedDescription);
```