# Create NSMutableDictionary with NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsmutabledictionary

I want to create a `NSMutableDictionnary` with a `NSString`.

```
-(NSMutableDictionary *)getList{
//Declaration d'un objet SQLITE
sqlite3 *database;

//Declaration de notre String qui sera retourne
NSMutableDictionary *aromaArray = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

// Ouverture de la base de donnees
if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {

    //Chaine de caracteres de la requete
    const char *sqlStatement = "SELECT name_fr FROM aroma_huiles";

    //Creation de l'objet statement
    sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;

    //Compilation de la requete et verification du succes
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

        // Creation d'un dictionnaire des noms de colonnes
        NSDictionary *dictionary = [self indexByColumnName:compiledStatement];
        //char **final = malloc(4096 * sizeof(*final));
        NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {

            //Assigne la valeur dans la chaine de caracteres
            char *tab;
            tab = (char*)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, [[dictionary objectForKey:@"name_fr"] intValue]);
            NSString *final = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:tab];
            if (final != nil) {
                NSString *firstLetter = [final substringToIndex:1];
                [aromaArray setObject:final forKey:firstLetter];
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        //Envois une exception en cas de probleme de requete
        NSAssert1(0, @"Erreur :. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }

    // Finalisation de la requete pour liberer la memoire
    sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);

}
else {
    //Envois une exception en cas de probleme d'ouverture
    NSAssert(0, @"Erreur d'ouverture de la base de donnees");
}
//Fermer la base de donnees
sqlite3_close(database);

//Retourne la valeur
return aromaArray;
```

}

I think this is the easiest method, only 2 lines, but It still reject it :

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1093180c0'
```

Comment: Add an exception breakpoint and Xcode will show you where this exception is being generated...

Comment: I know it's a loop problem but I can figure out how I can build a Dictionnary in an easy way ..

Comment: You've already fixed the loop problem. You are now getting a completely different error. You find the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18888059/cannot-find-executable-for-cfbundle-certuiframework-axbundle

Comment: The error changed now ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see is that your `array` variable is accessed outside of its bounds. There is simply no element after index `66` as it contains only 67 elements.

You are using a hard to read loop constructs when iterating over `array`. Instead of `while` in your case you can transform your loops to use the `for` construct:

```
for (int j = 0; j < [array count]; j++) {
...
    for (int i = 0; i < [array count]; i++) {
    ...
    }
}
```

Doing so there's no need anymore for resetting `i` to `0` and there's no need for increasing `i` and `j` outside of the loop header (remove `i++` and `j++` statements at the bottom of your loops).

Comment: Please post both nested loops how you implemented them using `for` constructs to http://pastebin.com and then give a link as a comment here.

Comment: I modified my first post with the for loop

Comment: You mixed up variable names. The second loop probably should say `for (int i = ...`. Remove declaration of `int i` from beginning of your code, it's now useless.

Comment: Yeah sorry I follow the exact code you posted .. My bad ! So it still doesn't work, not the same mistake now :
    Cannot find executable for CFBundle ....

Maybe there's an easiest way to build NSDictionnary ?

Comment: I corrected my code snippet. Update your question to reflect your exact problem.

Comment: My array is perfect, I really don't understand why these 2 simple loop won't work ..

Answer (score 0):

Change  `while (array[j])` to `while (j < [array count])`

Comment: I did this, and change the while with a for, but still the same error, and the log is good ..

Comment: Maybe, problem in string **NSString *firstLetter = [array[i] substringToIndex:1];** ? Change to **if(i < [array count]){NSString *firstLetter = [array[i] substringToIndex:1]}**

Comment: I don't think so it works fine, when I want to print firstLetter and secondLetter in the logs they are printed well, and the if is good ..

Comment: You have problem with index

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you directly create dictionary while you fetch data from DB

```
while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {

            //Assigne la valeur dans la chaine de caracteres
            char *tab;
            tab = (char*)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, [[dictionary objectForKey:@"name_fr"] intValue]);
            NSString *final = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:tab];
            if (final != nil && final.length >0) {
//get substring from string here
NSString *firstLetter = [final substringToIndex:1];
//Add objects in dictionary here
                    [aromaArray setObject:final forKey:firstLetter];
            }
        }
```

Comment: I'm Trying to do this : http://pastebin.com/DkVQdrXa 
But it tells me : 
    [__NSCFString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10973e5c0
2014-09-01 10:51:37.711 SQLite-TUO[22126:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10973e5c0'

Comment: You don't need to use any index you can directly pass string value in dictionary.

Comment: Also put a check for length of string.

Comment: Still the error : 
 
    *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x109532470'

Comment: ok I think it works , but my dictionnary only contains 1 value per key, it replace the previous value e.g : First time : G = "Great" , Second time : G = "Good",, but I want G = "Great", "Good" (and the error is still there but it comes from the viewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason for the crash is these lines

```
 tab = (char*)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, [[dictionary objectForKey:@"name_fr"] intValue]);
 NSString *final = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:tab];
```

if the char value is **nil** and is converted to the string value an exception may come.ie the case appear when basically there is no value in the corresponding row in table.

so try

```
tab = (char*)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, [[dictionary objectForKey:@"name_fr"] intValue]);
if(tab){
     NSString *final = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:tab];
     //everything else that comes under is to be here
}
```

Comment: Already check if (final != nil), it's the same. My problem is totaly different than what I thought ...

Comment: `stringWithUTF8String` may be the culprit

Answer (score 0):

So I finally manage to fix the problem ! Simple solution, a bit slow but still it works now ! 
My problem was totally different than what I thought at the begining.
I tried to make a Dictionnary with NSString, and the values were replaced at each loop .. So I only got 20 products when I had 84 at the begining, the Dictionnary was built, but It crashed because I nedded a DIctionnary made with NSArray ! I didn't notice that, so I finally find the solution (I will replace the while with for) :

```
tab = (char*)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, [[dictionary objectForKey:@"name_fr"] intValue]);
            NSString *final = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:tab];
            if (final != nil && final.length >0) {
                [array addObject:final];
            }
        }
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        NSMutableArray *table = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        while (i < [array count])
        {
            NSString *firstLetter = [array[i] substringToIndex:1];
            table = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            while (j < [array count])
            {
                NSString *secondLetter = [array[j] substringToIndex:1];
                if ([secondLetter isEqualToString:firstLetter]) {
                    [table addObject:array[j]];
                }
                j++;
            }
            j = 0;
            [aromaArray setObject:table forKey:firstLetter];
            i++;
        }
```

Thank you all for your help :)